# Installshield setup.exe change the installer language on repair/maintenance/uninstall

Tags: installshield, windows-installer

On a clean machine with the product not installed, I can run the setup.exe and it will show the language selection dialog OR run setup.exe with switch -L{LanguageCode}.

But running the setup.exe again for maintenance the language will be set to what it was to the first time install. It won't give you the language dialog. Using the switch method only changes the language of the first Welcome dialog, while the rest of the dialogs are in the first time install language.

I have tried looking at the `Language` key in the registry under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[MYPRODUCTCODEHERE]`. But its value is always 0 no matter what language I selected. So how does the Installer remember that language on the first time install? It must write it somewhere else right? I'm thinking of using external script/app which will modify that then call setup.exe

1. Where msi/installer/windows writes that value?
2. Any alternative way to change the language for maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield supports multiple languages in Windows Installer with a per-language transform. As a full transform, this can change data that is installed in addition to the text that shows in the wizard. Transforms can only be selected before installation begins, and Windows Installer caches this information somewhere, so you cannot change the language during a maintenance operation.

Comment: Would an external UI / suite installer help in some way?  Just hide the underlying MSI behavior?

Comment: There seems to be a recache command for MSI. [quote]v runs your application from the source and re-caches the local installation package from [link]http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ihelpcmdlinemsi.htm[link]
How can I translate that MSI switch command into a setup.exe switch command? Would re-caching even work?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: If you only care about the display language, then I think you can make the language selection dialog of the suite visible during maintenance to allow changing it. If you care about langauge-specific data in a transform you're still locked (though you could refactor that to other packages in a suite). So it depends on your actual needs.

Comment: @mhur: InstallShield will automatically recache on a minor upgrade, but swapping out a language transform that affects any data components could easily result in a violation of minor upgrade rules and leave files or registry behind. So I forget if a minor upgrade lets you select a new language via the UI or command line.